# Problem while writing sketch for GSM module sim800

Tags: gsm, sketch

I wanted to my GSM to recieve SMSs. I have written a sketch for it. But while verifying the sketch an error pops out in this part:

`if (sms.available()) {
      sms.remoteNumber(senderNnumber, 20);
      if (senderNumber == "09432167015") {
        c = sms.read();
      if (c == "yes") {
          alarm_police();
          }
        }
      }`   

The error message:

> Arduino: 1.6.5 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> GuardDog_v2.5.ino: In function 'void loop()':
>   GuardDog_v2.5:201: error: 'senderNnumber' was not declared in this scope
>   GuardDog_v2.5:204: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and >integer [-fpermissive]
>   'senderNnumber' was not declared in this scope
>
> This report would have more information with
>    "Show verbose output during compilation"
>    enabled in File > Preferences.

I have checked the receiving sms example and have written the sketch according to the example.I need help regarding this error and how to fix it

Comment: You have a scope problem and you are comparing a pointer to an integer. Show us the rest of your sketch and provide a link to the library u're using

Comment: The sketch is a bit too big and contains parts which are not related to GSM. Should I show the complete sketch? BTW the library I used is the default GSM library which is present in the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled the variable `senderNumber`. Correct it. Also you aren't reading the SMS properly or comparing the phone numbers properly. Your code should be like this (using the examples):

```
#define MAX_MSG 50

char senderNumber[20];
char sms_buf[MAX_MSG];   // a buffer for your sms, max len = 50

if (sms.available()) {    // this part should be in loop()
  sms.remoteNumber(senderNumber, 20);
  if (strcmp(senderNumber, "09432167015") == 0) { // compare numbers
    while (sms.available() == 0);   // wait for a char
    char i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_MSG - 1){    // till max len is reached; 1 byte for null
      c = sms.read();
      if (c == '\0')  // assuming the modem terminates sms with null
        break;
      sms_buf[i++] = c;   // write char to the buffer
      while (sms.available() == 0);   //wait for a char
    }
    sms_buf[i] = 0;   // terminate the string, just in case
    if (strstr(sms_buf, "yes") != NULL)  // look for 'yes' in buffer
      alarm_police();
  }
}
```

Comment: is MAX_MSG an int

Comment: It can be a char or int; just edited it

Comment: during the upload an error for char sms_buf[MAX_MSG]; pops up: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token.

Comment: Change MAX_MSG to int and try again

Comment: I had used int for MAX_MSG it doesn't work for both char and int

Comment: Oh, i remember now....use #define MAX_MSG 50

Comment: @Reptile1234 Array bounds have to be integer constants. So the previous declaration didnt work (unless u make it 'const int').